# Método dinâmico para abrir telas

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Estou criando um método para abrir qualquer tela que eu passar no parâmetro.

Fiz este método:

```
public async Task NavigateTo(Page page)
{
    await App.MasterDetail.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new page());    
}
```

Mas toda vez que vou compilar da um erro

```
CS0118  "page" é um variável, mas é usado como um tipo
```

O que é preciso fazer para funcionar?

Comment: em vez de colocar um new page, acho que você deve somente colocar o page, que está sendo enviado no parâmetro. Ao meu ver, dessa forma você estará iniciando uma página que nem existe.

Comment: Beleza @Samuel, vou tentar assim para ver no que da

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente mudar disso:

```
public async Task NavigateTo(Page page)
{
    await App.MasterDetail.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new page());    
}
```

Para:

```
public async Task NavigateTo(Page page)
{
    await App.MasterDetail.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(page);    
}
```

Comment: Valeu carinha era isso mesmo :D